# Как сверстать такое верхнее меню (android)

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Есть такое меню [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут просто подложка, и на ней логотип (центр). Как будет правильно сверстать это на android ? Какие лайауты использовать, и как их заполнять? Если можно пример )) 
Спасибо

Comment: где здесь меню, подложка, логотип? Я вижу заголовок и картинку - `LinearLayout` `android:orientation = "vertical"`

Comment: @pavlofff , а как залить лианерлайоут, фоном как под надписью "DOTA 2 КРОКОДИЛ" ?? Спасибо )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **activity_main.xml** вставь код разметки:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DOTA 2 КРОКОДИЛ"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/black_gradient"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/your_image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

В **res/drawable** создай новый **Resource Drawable file** и назови его **black_gradient**. Затем в него вставь код, приведенный ниже.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/gray_holo_dark"
        android:endColor="@color/black"
        android:angle="-270" />
</shape>
```

Должен получиться градиент. Может быть придется изменить цвета **@color/gray_holo_dark** и **@color/black**, чтобы добиться необходимого градиента.